# SharePoint 2013 Retriving documents without DirName and ListID

Tags: sharepoint

I like to check on how to retrieve documents that does not belong to any List or Document Library.

Currently the documents URL in search result is something like this "http://example.com/file.doc"

I suspect the documents where at this location due to data importing using PowerShell script and the script was unable to get the path that I was uploading to.

I will like to get the details of documents like this and delete them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://example.com
$web.Files | select Url
```

if you would like to retreive from all subwebs the code would be:

```
foreach ($inWeb in $web)
{
    $inWeb.Files | select Url
}
```

Comment: The first solution works for me. Thank you. Managed to retrieve relative url by selection ServerRelativeUrl

Comment: happy to hear that. mark as answered if it resolves your issue :)